# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on WSL when log model with MLFlow

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, mlflow

[Permission Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL4D1.png)

I have this problem when I try to save the model using MLFlow on WSL.

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/c'

My code is

```
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI)
mlflow.set_registry_uri(MLFLOW_REGISTRY_URI)

with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    reg = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.1)
    reg.fit([[0, 0], [1, 1]], [0, 1])
    mlflow.sklearn.log_model(sk_model=reg, artifact_path="model")
```

Comment: Where do you run the mlflow tracking server?

Answer (score 0):

MLFlow is not able to write to the given location of artifact URI.

We can set the path: `mlflow.set_tracking_uri(f"file://{MLFLOW_PATH}")` and give the folder required permission.